# Meteor.http.call gives not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: meteor

When I try to call an external server for JSON queries in Meteor with the `Meteor.http.call("GET")` method I get the error message "not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

How do I allow my meteor app to make HTTP calls to other servers? 
Right now I run it on localhost.

The code I run is this:

```
Meteor.http.call("GET", 
                 "http://api.vasttrafik.se/bin/rest.exe/v1/location.name?authKey=XXXX&format=json&jsonpCallback=processJSON&input=kungsportsplatsen", 
                  function(error, result) {
                          console.log("test");    
                      }
                 );
```

Answer (score 4):

There are other questions similar to this on StackOverflow.

You're restricted by the server you're trying to connect to when you do this from the client side (AJAX).

One way to solve it is if you have access to the external server, you can modify the header file to allow some, or all  origins by:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

However, if you place the call on the server side and not provide a callback function, the call will be made synchronously, thus not with AJAX, and it should succeed.

Here's

```
Meteor.methods({checkTwitter: function (userId) {
   this.unblock();
   var result = Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://api.twitter.com/xyz", {params: {user: userId}});
   if (result.statusCode === 200) return true
   return false;
}});
```

Comment: How could you add this to your response objects? So that it will enable CORS or something like that? Code snippet maybe?