# Meteor.http.call() from my app.meteor.com

Tags: javascript, meteor, ddp

I have an application where I use Meteor.http.call() in a server side function.

```
var ret = Meteor.http.call("GET", "https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/SF1/<...>");
```

This works using a localhost meteor server: I have my data back in the `ret` variable.
I deployed the application to `ruleoneinvesting.meteor.com` and now I get this error using that same call:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ddp--4645-ruleoneinvesting.meteor.com/sockjs/info?cb=p7czcbhqun. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ruleoneinvesting.meteor.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508275/meteor-http-call-gives-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault. I was using a

```
fs.writeFile('../../../../../../data/')
```

in a folder that it was not allowed to write in `*.meteor.com`.
That caused the HTTP status code `503`.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're getting "HTTP status code 503", this may not be something you can or need to fix.

According to [wicked peter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error), the problem may not be yours but the server's:

```
503 Service Unavailable
The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance). Generally, this is a temporary state
```